# Failing to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups when using rank()

Tags: hive, hiveql, window-functions

I have a dataset of properties and I'm trying to rank the each segment by it's property count. I then want to assign the segment with most properties as the segment for the xml_id which manages these properties. I have tried this:

```
select
    yyyy_mm_dd,
    xml_id,
    ps_segment
from(
    select
        pspd.yyyy_mm_dd,
        xppd.xml_id,
        ps.ps_segment,
        count(pspd.property_id) as property_count.
        rank() over (partition by pspd.yyyy_mm_dd order by count(pspd.property_id) desc) rn 
    from(
        select
            yyyy_mm_dd,
            property_id
        from
            t1
    ) pspd
    left join(
        select
            yyyy_mm_dd,
            property_id,
            xml_id
        from
            t2
    ) xppd on xppd.property_id = pspd.property_id and xppd.yyyy_mm_dd = pspd.yyyy_mm_dd
    inner join
        t3 ps on ps.property_id = property_id
    group by
        1,2,3
) x
where
    rn = 1
```

The above throws the following error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies. Underlying error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 5:50 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'property_count'

So essentially `xml_id` ends up with the `ps_segment` which has the highest property count. What am I doing wrong in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by myself and the below query works. It seems I should have been using `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()`:

```
select
    yyyy_mm_dd,
    xml_id,
    ps_segment
from(
    select
        pspd.yyyy_mm_dd,
        xppd.xml_id,
        ps.ps_segment,
        count(pspd.property_id) as property_count,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by pspd.yyyy_mm_dd, xml_id order by count(pspd.property_id) desc) rn
    from(
        select
            yyyy_mm_dd,
            property_id
        from
            t1
        where
            and yyyy_mm_dd = '2019-10-10'
    ) pspd
    left join(
        select
            yyyy_mm_dd,
            property_id,
            xml_id
        from
            t2
        where
            yyyy_mm_dd = '2019-10-10'
    ) xppd on xppd.property_id = pspd.property_id and xppd.yyyy_mm_dd = pspd.yyyy_mm_dd
    inner join
        t3 ps on ps.hotel_id = pspd.hotel_id
    group by
        1,2,3
) x
where
    rn = 1
```